# Different results from using HMACSHA256 ComputeHash when used in C# and VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, hash, encoding, hmacsha1

The request is being created in a VB application.

```vb
Dim unixTimeStamp As Int64
Dim currenttime = DateTime.Now
currenttime = currenttime.AddHours(1)

Dim dt = currenttime.ToUniversalTime
Dim unixEpoch = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
unixTimeStamp = (dt.Subtract(unixEpoch)).TotalMilliseconds

Dim nonce = unixTimeStamp
Dim message = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", ClientId, nonce, Token)

Dim encodin = New ASCIIEncoding
Dim MessageBytes() As Byte = encodin.GetBytes(message)
Dim KeyBytes() As Byte = encodin.GetBytes(apiSecret)

Dim Signature As String
Using myHMACSHA256 As New HMACSHA256(KeyBytes)
Dim hashmessage() As Byte
    hashmessage = myHMACSHA256.ComputeHash(MessageBytes)
    Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage)
End Using

Dim strHeader = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", APIKey, Token, nonce, Signature)
Return strHeader
```

Values are decoded in a C# application and then the hash is recreated for comparison.

```c#
string msg = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", clientId, nonce, token);
string result;

var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(privateKey);
byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(msg);
using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
{
    byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    result = Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
}

return result == clientSignature;
```

In this example, `MessageBytes` (vb) and `messageBytes` (c#) are identical byte arrays. The same goes for `keyBytes` for both.

However, when `hmacsha256.ComputeHash` is called, I am receiving different results.
Both byte arrays are the same length but the contents are completely different.

My understanding is that different results can only be given for different inputs? Is there anything obvious here that I'm missing?

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced by the information you provided so far. Please create a [repro] with sample values of `message`/`msg` and `apiSecret`/`privateKey`. Once you do that, you probably will find out that the values of both `hashmessage` arrays are identical and that the problem most likely lies somewhere else. Try to narrow that down and if you still can't figure it out by then, you may provide us with the new [repro].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by the user in question being a special case that was working with another developer to get their plugin working.
They had been given a newly generated API secret and had failed to relay this information.
The code above works as intended...

Answer (score 0):

I was instantiating HMACSHA256 without specifying a key in the constructor.  If you don't specify a key in the constructor, HMACSHA256 will generate a random key, and calling the ComputeHash() method will generate a different hash for each instance.  You must specify the key if you want consistent hash value for a given string.

Constructors
HMACSHA256()
Initializes a new instance of the HMACSHA256 class with a randomly generated key.

HMACSHA256(Byte[])
Initializes a new instance of the HMACSHA256 class with the specified key data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=net-8.0